# Handling cache beyong Nginx server and webpack js and css versioning

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, caching, nginx

I have a React nodejs app running on EC2.

I have set up 3 instances of it beyond Nginx for the load balancing.

I have also enabled cache in the Nginx configuration.

Basically everything should be cached beside different versions of app.js which holds the bundled React code and style.css which is also bundled.

I would like to add a version number in the js and css src link (e.g http://mywebsite.com/app.js?1.0)

My question is, can I automate this operation with webpack? Is this the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`html-webpack-plugin` is your friend here.

Instead of creating your index.html file, allow webpack to do it for you.

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/app.bundle.[hash].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: true,
            filename: './dist/index.html'
        })
   ]

}
```

This will add the output script into index.html automatically and will generate a hash for the file.

Comment: Great did the trick, both for js and css. However I have noticed that if you set hash to true, it adds ?[hash] to the src link which is not recommended by google speed test and other benchmarking tools. I have removed it and just added it to the file name as you recommended. I have also used the template option because I have some initial things there I would like to keep. Thanks again